# Javascript, GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, mouseevent

I have a hidden component that will be shown only if a mouse pointer is in some area (not necessary on top of the hidden component).  Therefore, I am interested in catching all mouse move event from the browser.  Is it posible with GWT, GXT, or with Javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to detect mouse events.

For example if you are using jQuery:

```
    $(document).mousemove(function(event){

       var mouseX = event.clientX;
       var mouseY = event.clientY;

       //do something with the X and Y values

    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/xqULX/